# Why a browser designed to parse html, css, javascript only?

Tags: browser

I am learning how a browser works. Can anybody explain why browsers are designed to render html only even if we write web application in other server languages like php, python, ruby on rails?.

Comment: Because browser works at client side. Applications written in server-side languages run at server-side and emit HTML which is then rendered at client-side.

Comment: As opposed to them doing what? A browser consumes HTML and does not care what produced it.

Comment: That's what a browser does. It's like asking why a C compiler doesn't wash the dishes for you.

Comment: I know that's what a browser does. One of the main reason is that they are web standards. This means they are rules that you can learn to follow. Without standards, HTML and CSS could do anything that anyone could come up with, which would be much harder to learn. Standards mean that when you write <a href="http://webdesign.about.com">Learn Web Design</a> a link is created on the page like this: Learn Web Design. Without standards, some browsers would support <a href... and others would support <link ... and others would support <anchor... and so on. Web designers would have to learn all of th

Answer (score 0):

Because other languages like php, nees's a "motor" to run, and then motor here is server, witch will send html to browser for parsing. Heres a picture, cuz everybody love's pictures.
[image]

EDIT: In between 3 and 4 it will do necessary php running etc.